# Base conversion explanation in assembly

Tags: assembly, radix

I really need further explanation on the codes given in these labels:

```
ACCEPT,INC_CTR,EXIT,BIN_ACCEPT,DISP_ZERO,
HEX_ACCEPT,LETTERS,SECOND_DIGIT, CONVERTTOOCTAL
```

I need this in order to understand further how the inputs were converted to several bases. I do understand the data definitions and the code, but the whole thing is too complicated.

```
.model small
.stack 90h   

.data 
counter db 0
curValue db 0
prevValue db 0 
hexa db 0
octal db 0 
msg db "Enter a decimal number: $"
msg2 db "In binary: $"
octmsg db "In octall: $"
hexmsg db "In hexadecimal: $"

.code
mov ax, @data           ;initialize DS
mov ds, ax 

;mov counter, 0              ;load and display the string msg
mov ah, 09h
lea dx, msg         
int 21h

accept: 
mov ah, 01          
int 21h                 ;read a digit

cmp al, 13              ;compare al with 13
je exit                 ;jump to label exit if input is 13 

sub al, 48              ;subract al with 48
mov curValue, al         ;move al to curValue

cmp counter, 1              ;compare counter with 1
jl inc_ctr            ;jump to label inc_ctr if al<1

mov al, prevValue        ;move prevValue to al
mov bl, 10
mul bl

add al, curValue         ;add curValue to al

mov prevValue, al        ;move al tp prevValue

inc counter                 ;inc_ctr counter
jmp accept              ;jump to label accept

inc_ctr:
mov prevValue, al        ;move al to prevValue 

inc counter                 ;inc_ctr counter
jmp accept              ;jump to label accept

exit:
mov bl,prevValue         ;move prevValue to bl
mov hexa, bl            ;move bl to hexa
mov bl, 0               ;move 0 to bl

mov ah, 02h             ;set output function
mov dl, 13              ;set dl to 13
int 21h                 ;print the character

mov ah, 02h             ;set output function
mov dl, 10              ;set dl to 10
int 21h                 ;print character

mov ah, 09h             ;load and display the string msg2
lea dx, msg2     
int 21h

binAccept:
cmp bl, 8               ;compare bl with 8
jge hexAccept          ;jump to hexAccept if bl>=0
rol prevValue, 1         ;rotate prevValue 1x
jnc dispZero
mov ah, 02              ;set output function
mov dl, '1'             ;display 1
int 21h                 ;print the character

inc bl
jmp binAccept        ;jump to label binAccept

dispZero:
mov ah, 02h             ;set the output function
mov dl, '0'             ;display 0
int 21h                 ;print the character

inc bl                  ;inc_ctr bl
jmp binAccept        ;jump to label binary accept

hexAccept: 
mov ah, 02h             ;set output function
mov dl, 13              ;set dl to 13
int 21h                 ;print the character

mov ah, 02h             ;set the output function
mov dl, 10              ;set dl to 10
int 21h                 ;print the character

mov ah, 09h             ;load and display the string hexmsg
lea dx, hexmsg
int 21h 

mov bl,hexa             ;move hexa to bl
mov octal, bl            ;move bl to octal
xor bx, bx             ;clear bx

mov bh, 240             ;move 240 to bh
and bh, hexa            ;multiply hexa with bh
mov bl, 15              ;move 15 to bl 
and bl, hexa            ;multiply hexa with bl

mov cl, 4               ;move 4 to cl
rol bh, cl              ;rotate bh 4x

cmp bh, 9               ;compare bh with 9
jg Letters        ;jump to Letters if bh>9
add bh, 48              ;add 48 to bh
mov ah, 02h             ;set the output function
mov dl, bh              ;move bh to dl
int 21h                 ;print the character
jmp Second_digit     ;jump to Second_digit

Letters:
add bh, 55              ;add 55 to bh

mov ah, 02h             ;set the output function
mov dl, bh              ;move bh to dl
int 21h                 ;print the character

Second_digit:       
cmp bl, 9               ;compare bl with 9
jg dispSecond_digit       ;jump to dispSecond_digit if bl>9
add bl, 48              ;add 48 to bl
mov ah, 02h             ;set the outputfunction
mov dl, bl              ;move bl to dl
int 21h                 ;print the character
jmp convertTooctall      ;jump to convertTooctall

dispSecond_digit:
add bl, 55              ;add 55 ot bl
mov ah, 02h             ;set the output function
mov dl, bl              ;move bl to dl
int 21h                 ;print the character

convertTooctall:
mov ah, 02h             ;set the output function
mov dl, 13              ;move 13 to dl
int 21h                 ;print the charater

mov ah, 02h             ;set the output function
mov dl, 10              ;move 10 to dl
int 21h                 ;print the character

mov ah, 09h             ;load and display the string ctmsg
lea dx, octmsg
int 21h 

mov bh, octal            ;move octal to bh

and bh, 192             ;multiply 192 to bh          
mov cl, 2               ;move 2 to cl
rol bh, cl              ;rotate bh 2x

add bh, 48              ;add 48 to bh 
mov ah, 02              ;set the output function
mov dl, bh              ;move bh to dl
int 21h                 ;print the character

mov bh, octal            ;move octal to bh
and bh, 56              ;add 56 to bh
mov cl, 5               ;move 5 to cl
rol bh, cl              ;rotate bh 5x
add bh, 48              ;add 48 to bh
mov ah, 02              ;set the output function
mov dl, bh              ;move bh to dl
int 21h                 ;print the character

mov bh, octal            ;move octal to bh
and bh, 7               ;mulptiply by 7

add bh, 48              ;add 48 to bh
mov ah, 02              ;set the output function
mov dl, bh              ;move bh to dl
int 21h                 ;print the character

mov ah, 04ch            ;return control to DOS
int 21h
```

Answer (score 0):

The code uses special cases and tricks, but behind the scene it ends up be the same as this:

Basic conversion from binary (machine code) to human readable/printable ASCII for binary, octal, hexadecimal (decimal or any base) is done by:

1. if the number is zero, place a "0" in the buffer and go to step 7
2. set base to the wished for output mode; e.g. 2, 8, 16 or 10
3. divide the number by the base, keep the remainder and store the quotient back as number for next iteration.
4. use the remainder as index into a table with characters "0123456789ABCDEF" and pick put the character
5. *Prepend* the character to the buffer
6. If the **quotient** (step 3) is not zero, go back to step 3
7. The exit: At this point the buffer holds your output string.

Now note that dividing by 10 is a bit tricky in assembly language, unless you have an instruction for division (not covered in this short text).
Division by 2, 4, 8, or 16 is equal to one, two, three or four bit shifts to the right (=division by 2^n, with n=1,2,3 or 4). For these, the remainder can be picked out - before the division - with an appropriate mask in an "and"-instruction.

*Negative numbers: detect it, set a flag for a pending "minus sign" to be prepended to the buffer before exit, negate the number and use the algorithm above, remember to prepend the minus sign before exit/display.*

Comment: I can't seem to understand how ROL (rotate left) in the binAccept: label does the conversion from decimal to binary..Is it a way of dividing the inputted digits by 2s or what?

Comment: The labels named `bin...` in the shown source code is likely to be within code to convert into a printable string of **binary** digits. ROL = rotate left => multiply by two for each step (while no overflow).